# How to handle web crawling using robots.txt for different subdomain- allow abc.sample.com but disallow cde.sample.com

Tags: web-crawler, subdomain, robots.txt

Currently we are having two subdomain for my sites, lets say abc.sample.com and cde.sample.com. Now, we would like to avoid crawling for the specific subdomain abc.sample.com but for cde.sample.com crawling needs to be support.

We have same set of code for both site so, the robots.txt also will be same.

On exploring about robot.txt it seems like we can avoid/ allow crawling for the different page of same site, but I need to do crawling of my site based on the subdomain.

Comment: Try to be more specific. What did you try?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego - I have updated my question. In short, we would like to avoid crawling for one of our subdomain using robots.txt